# Cannot find global type 'Array'

Tags: node.js, typescript, webpack

I'm getting this message when I'm trying to get started my app:

Command:

```
npm webpack --config config/webpack.prod.js  --progress --profile --bail
```

Message:

> Error in bail mode: [default]
>   Cannot find global type 'Array'.

typescript: 2.0.8 is included on `package.json`

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm getting the same, i think a dependency has changed and broke it. Because it was working fine for me yesterday, then I wiped out `node_modules` and reinstalled, and got this message. So its a dependency changed issue. Check your "~" and "^" dependencies

Comment: If you remove `--bail` mode, you can see the full list of errors. It will show you many dozens of Type errors, something with TypeScript is busted.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by doing these steps:

1. Removing all `~` and `^` prefixes from package dependencies, so they stop auto-updating and breaking stuff.
2. Updating to `awesome-typescript-loader@2.2.4` - version `^2.2.1` was not working suddenly for some reason. Neither did `2.2.1` (without the `^`)

That fixed the build Type errors for me.